# Best scenarios to use ajax

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm building a website application where users post contents using a form similar to blog-entry forms, this form allows uploading of files, has a wysiwyg editor, etc.

Now since it will be posting a lot of data, should I go for ajax?

Comment: This is not a UX question but a technical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is always a viable option. It's just a technology that you can use, it shouldn't really matter to the user what technology you picked. The challenge is in execution.

An interface that simply uses old fashioned POST/GET etc. solves a number of things that aren't clearcut in AJAX. With a standard form, nothing happens while you're entering data, your browser remembers what you put in, you submit stuff to the server, server looks at it, gives some information back, you get a page refresh and some feedback. When you're using AJAX you need to be much more careful about providing feedback. One of the reasons I recently switched to Adminer over PHPMyAdmin is the latter's terribly poor AJAX implementation. Technically I bet that it works, but it is not always clear that data is being sent to the server, it is not always clear if that has been succesful, etc.

I'm a big fan of simple, high performance PHP implementations for simple things like forms, because they put the user in control without a lot of effort in design and development.

Comment: This is not a UX question.

Comment: I know, this is somewhat of an UX answer though ;)

Answer (score -1):

My first reaction was: "NO". Then Gmail came to my mind as an example. So, yes, you could go for AJAX. The amount of data is not the argument though...

Comment: Hello, thanks. What's the argument then?

Comment: Not freezing the UI while performing an upload, in general. The delay often comes from waiting for the server response, not always because of a large file size.